# How can I center columns in a row in bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>

<style>

    h1 {
        text-align: center;
        color: white;
    }

    #box {
        background: #005A31;
        position: relative;
        top: 25vh;
        width: 50%;
    }

    #results {
        background: #F3FAB6;
        margin: 1%;
        text-align: right;
        font-size: 300%;
    }

    .buttons {
        background: #A8CD1B;
        margin: 1%;
        text-align: center;
        display: inline-block;
        border: hidden;
        border-radius: 20%;
        font-size: 200%;
        padding: 4%;
    }

    .buttons:hover {
        cursor: pointer;
        background: #F3FAB6; !important
    }

    .operations {
        background: #CBE32D;
    }

    .center-block {
        float: none !important;
    }


</style>

<html>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="container" id="box">
            <h1>JavaScript Calculator</h1>
            <div id="results">0</div>
            <div class="row">
                <div id="seven" class="buttons col-md-2 center-block">7</div>
                <div id="eight" class="buttons col-md-2 center-block">8</div>
                <div id="nine" class="buttons col-md-2 center-block">9</div>
                <div id="multiply" class="buttons operations col-md-3 center-block">x</div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div id="four" class="buttons col-md-2 center-block">4</div>
                <div id="five" class="buttons col-md-2 center-block">5</div>
                <div id="six" class="buttons col-md-2 center-block">6</div>
                <div id="divide" class="buttons operations col-md-3 center-block">/</div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div id="one" class="buttons col-md-2 center-block">1</div>
                <div id="two" class="buttons col-md-2 center-block">2</div>
                <div id="three" class="buttons col-md-2 center-block">3</div>
                <div id="add" class="buttons operations col-md-3 center-block">+</div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div id="decimal" class="buttons col-md-2 center-block">.</div>
                <div id="zero" class="buttons col-md-2 center-block">0</div>
                <div id="ans" class="buttons col-md-2 center-block operations">Ans</div>
                <div id="equals" class="buttons col-md-3 operations center-block">=</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>    
</html>
```

I'm trying to create a JavaScipt calculator. I've got the basic stuff down, but I just can't seem to center the `<div>`'s that I've created for buttons. I'm trying to use the center-block property for bootstrap, but that doesn't seem to change anything.

See this JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/uqfd88o5/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added a container div `id="rowcontainer"` for all the buttons. Then added a CSS `text-align:center;` to that container

```
<html>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="container" id="box">
            <h1>JavaScript Calculator</h1>
            <div id="results">0</div>
            <div id="rowcontainer">


            <div class="row">
                <div id="seven" class="buttons col-md-2 center-block">7</div>
                <div id="eight" class="buttons col-md-2 center-block">8</div>
                <div id="nine" class="buttons col-md-2 center-block">9</div>
                <div id="multiply" class="buttons operations col-md-3 center-block">x</div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div id="four" class="buttons col-md-2 center-block">4</div>
                <div id="five" class="buttons col-md-2 center-block">5</div>
                <div id="six" class="buttons col-md-2 center-block">6</div>
                <div id="divide" class="buttons operations col-md-3 center-block">/</div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div id="one" class="buttons col-md-2 center-block">1</div>
                <div id="two" class="buttons col-md-2 center-block">2</div>
                <div id="three" class="buttons col-md-2 center-block">3</div>
                <div id="add" class="buttons operations col-md-3 center-block">+</div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div id="decimal" class="buttons col-md-2 center-block">.</div>
                <div id="zero" class="buttons col-md-2 center-block">0</div>
                <div id="ans" class="buttons col-md-2 center-block operations">Ans</div>
                <div id="equals" class="buttons col-md-3 operations center-block">=</div>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>    
</html>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```